# Take screenshot of a splash screen in mobile application

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium

I need to take the screenshot of a welcome screen which flashes for 1-2 seconds before landing the home page. By the time I take the screenshot in the second line after the driver initialization application reached the home page. How can I take the screenshot before reaching the home page.

```
driver = new AndroidDriver<AndroidElement>(new Uri(AppConfiguration.AppiumServerUrl), appCapabilities);
                    driver.TakeScreenshot();
```

Application is a mobile Android application.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you **can't.**

When you initialize the driver it goes through the process of launching the application, and waiting till it is correctly started before issuing any commands.

Unfortunately, this is only achieved once the splash screen is no longer visible.